# Writing out some propositions using disjunctions and conjunctions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Suppose that the universe of discourse of the atomic formula $P(x,y)$ is $\{1, 2, 3\}$.   Write out the following propositions using disjunctions and conjunctions.

a) $\exists x \forall y \ P(x,y)$

Because there exists at least one $x$ for all $y$, my awnser is: $$\bigl(P(1,1) \lor P(1,2) \lor P(1,3)\bigr) \land \bigl(P(2,1) \lor P(2,2) \lor P(2,3)\bigr) \land \bigl(P(3,1) \lor P(3,2) \lor P(3,3)\bigr).$$

However my awnser doesn't seems to be right.

Comment: Work step-by-step: $∀y P(x,y)$ is $P(x,1) \land P(x,2) \land P(x,3)$.

Comment: You need to swap $\land$ with $\lor$ to get the right answer (arrow-turning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An universal quantifier is conjunctive over the domain, where as an existential quantifier is disjunctive.

- If something is true *for all* entities, then it's true for this *and* that *and* every other entity.
- If something is true *for some* entity, then it's true for this *or* that *or* some other entity.

---

$$\exists x~\forall y~P(x,y) {~=~ \bigvee_{x\in\mathcal D}\bigwedge_{y\in\mathcal D}P(x,y) \\~=~ (\bigwedge_{y\in\mathcal D}P(1,y))\vee(\bigwedge_{y\in\mathcal D}P(2,y))\vee(\bigwedge_{y\in\mathcal D}P(3,y))\\~=~ (P(1,1)\wedge P(1,2)\wedge P(1,3))\vee(\bigwedge_{y\in\mathcal D}P(2,y))\vee(\bigwedge_{y\in\mathcal D}P(3,y))\\~~\vdots}$$